# Python / smallest positive integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took following codility demo task 
Write a function:

def solution(A)

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

My Solution

```py
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    l = len(A)
    B = []
    result = 0
    n = 0
    for i in range(l):
        if A[i] >=1:
            B.append(A[i]) 
    if B ==[]:
        return(1)
    else:    
       B.sort() 
       B = list(dict.fromkeys(B))
       n = len(B)
       for j in range(n-1):
           if B[j+1]>B[j]+1:
                result = (B[j]+1)
       if result != 0:
            return(result)
       else:
            return(B[n-1]+1)
```

Although I get correct output for all inputs I tried but my score was just 22%. Could somebody please highlight where I am going wrong.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/amp/

Comment: "my score was just 22%" Can you clarify what you mean by that? Are there automated tests in which you get the wrong results? Can you please provide the input, expected output and actual output for cases you fail?

Answer (score 9):

Python solution with O(N) time complexity and O(N) space complexity:

```
def solution(A):
    arr = [0] * 1000001
    for a in A:
        if a>0:
            arr[a] = 1
    for i in range(1, 1000000+1):
        if arr[i] == 0:
            return i
```

My main idea was to:

1. creat a zero-initialized "buckets" for all the positive possibilities.
2. Iterate over A. Whenever you meet a positive number, mark it's bucket as visited (1).
3. Iterate over the "buckets" and return the first zero "bucket".

Answer (score 2):

```
def solution(A):
    
    s = set(A)
    for x in range(1,100002):
        if x not in s:
            return x
    pass
```

And GOT 100%

Comment: Confirmed, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

```
# you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# print("this is a debug message")
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    i = 1;
    B = set(A);
    while True:
        if i not in B:
            return i;
        i+=1;
```

Comment: Score: 100%. Passes all test cases.

Answer (score 1):

My Javascript solution. The solution is to sort the array and compare the adjacent elements of the array. Complexity is O(N)

```
function solution(A) {
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
  A.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  if (A[0] > 1 || A[A.length - 1] < 0 || A.length <= 2) return 1;

  for (let i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
    if (A[i] > 0 && (A[i + 1] - A[i]) > 1) {
        return A[i] + 1;
    }
  }

  return A[A.length - 1] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Codility you must predict correctly others inputs, not only the sample ones and also get a nice performance. I've done this way:

```
from collections import Counter
def maior_menos_zero(A):
    if A < 0:
        return 1

    else:
        return 1 if A != 1 else 2

def solution(A):
    if len(A) > 1:
        copia = set(A.copy())
        b = max(A)
        c = Counter(A)
        if len(c) == 1:
            return maior_menos_zero(A[0])

        elif 1 not in copia:
            return 1

        else:
            for x in range(1,b+2):
                if x not in copia:
                    return x
    else:
        return maior_menos_zero(A[0])
```

Got it 100%. If is an array **A** of **len(A) == 1**, function `maior_menos_zero` will be called. Moreover, if it's an **len(A) > 1** but its elements are ***the same (Counter)***, then function `maior_menos_zero` will be called again. Finally, if **1** is not in the array, so **1** is the **smallest positive integer** in it, otherwise **1** is in it and we shall make a ***for X in range(1,max(A)+2)*** and check if its elements are in **A**, futhermore, to save time, the first ocurrence of ***X not in A*** is **the smallest positive integer**.

Answer (score 0):

My solution (100% acceptance):

```
def solution(nums):

    nums_set = set()
    for el in nums:
        if el > 0 and el not in nums_set:
            nums_set.add(el)

    sorted_set = sorted(nums_set)

    if len(sorted_set) == 0:
        return 1

    if sorted_set[0] != 1:
        return 1

    for i in range(0, len(sorted_set) - 1, 1):
        diff = sorted_set[i + 1] - sorted_set[i]
        if diff >= 2:
            return sorted_set[i] + 1

    return sorted_set[-1] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, and got 100% score

```
def solution(A):

    A_set = set(A)
    for x in range(10**5 + 1, 1):
        if x not in A_set:
            return x
    else:
        return 10**5 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**This solution  is an easy approach!**

```py
def solution(A):
...     A.sort()
...     maxval = A[-1]
...     nextmaxval = A[-2]
...     if maxval < 0:
...             while maxval<= 0:
...                     maxval += 1
...             return maxval
...     else:
...             if nextmaxval + 1 in A:
...                     return maxval +1
...             else:
...                     return nextmaxval + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.8.10
    new = set(A)
    max_ = abs(max(A)) #use the absolute here for negative maximum value
    for num in range(1,max_+2):
        if num not in new:
            return num
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution using sets (not depending on the boundaries for the problem):

```
def solution(A):
    a_positive = [x for x in A if x > 0]
    set_a_positive = set(a_positive)
    if not set_a_positive:
        return 1
    
    max_a_positive = max(a_positive)
    set_b = set(range(1, max_a_positive + 2))
    return min(set_b ^ set_a_positive)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I am assuming the list is not sorted but if it is sorted you can remove the `number_list = sorted(number_list)` to make it a little bit faster.

```
def get_smallest_positive_integer(number_list):
    if all(number < 0 for number in number_list) or 1 not in number_list:
        #checks if numbers in list are all negative integers or if 1 is not in list
        return 1
    else:
        try:
            #get the smallest number in missing integers
            number_list = sorted(number_list) # remove if list is already sorted by default
            return min(x for x in range(number_list[0], number_list[-1] + 1) if x not in number_list and x != 0)
        except:
            #if there is no missing number in list get largest number + 1
            return max(number_list) + 1


print(get_smallest_positive_integer(number_list))
```

input:

```
number_list = [1,2,3]
```

output:

```
>>4
```

input:

```
number_list = [-1,-2,-3]
```

output:

```
>>1
```

input:

```
number_list = [2]
```

output:

```
>>1
```

input:

```
number_list = [12,1,23,3,4,5,61,7,8,9,11]
```

output:

```
>>2
```

input:

```
number_list = [-1,3,2,1]
```

output:

```
>>4
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be as easy as starting at 1 and checking which number first fails to appear.

```
def solution(A):
    i = 1
    while i in A:
        i += 1

    return i
```

You can also consider putting A's elements into a set (for better performance on the search), but I'm not sure that it's worth for this case.

**Update:**
I've been doing some tests with the numbers OP gave (numbers from negative million to positive million and 100000 elements).

```
100000 elements:
Linear Search: 0.003s
Set Search: 0.017s

1000000 elements (extra test):
Linear Search: 0.8s
Set Search: 2.58s
```

Comment: This is an inefficient, n² time complexity solution. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity at least convert `A` to a set, it's definitely worth it.